# Cross compile GCC and GDB with Yocto

Tags: gcc, gdb, cross-compiling, yocto

Is there any way to cross compile `gcc` and `gdb` using the `bitbake` command in `YOCTO` project?

Comment: I am trying to compile `gcc` toolchain for `imx6q` microprocessor. The image that comes with the `sabresd` platform does not contain `gcc` installed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I get you correctly you want to add `gcc` and `gdb` to the image.
The easiest and cleanest solution I know is to enable them via `EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES`.
Typically, you configure this variable in your `local.conf` file, which is found in the Build Directory. Although you can use this variable from within a recipe, best practices dictate that you do not. [1]

```
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES = "tools-sdk tools-debug"
```

[1] http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES

Answer (score 1):

To create the image-based SDK, For example, run this:

`$ bitbake core-image-full-cmdline -c populate_sdk`

With that, the SDK is created based on the `core-image-full-cmdline` image.
After it is done, the binary script can be found at `/build/tmp/deploy/sdk/poky-eglibc-x86_64-core-image-full-cmdline-armv5te-toolchain-1.6.sh`

To create generic SDK, use `meta-toolchain`

`$ bitbake meta-toolchain`

Find how to set up Qt [here](http://wiki.hioproject.org/index.php?title=HIO_Wiki:Set_Up_Qt_Creator_for_Yocto_Device)